# How to log messages received by ActiveMQ Artemis to log file?

Tags: logging, activemq-artemis

Can someone tell me how to configure ActiveMQ Artemis to log incoming messages (added to queue). 
Is it possible?

I tried to log all in audit.log according to documentation but without success.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help others who may have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html). A configuration like this should get you what you want:

```xml
<broker-plugins>
   <broker-plugin class-name="org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl.LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin">
      <property key="LOG_SENDING_EVENTS" value="true" />
   </broker-plugin>
</broker-plugins>
```

Comment: Forgive my stupid question: how do you install the plugin? Also, do you know if this is also available for the classic version of ActiveMQ (not Artemis)?

Comment: The [broker plugins documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html) links to [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-server.html#adding-runtime-dependencies) about how to add the plugin to the classpath. ActiveMQ "Classic" does support plugins, but the interface is completely different from ActiveMQ Artemis.